# Insert date yyyy-mm-dd from text file to teradata table

Tags: date, teradata, date-formatting, date-conversion, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to insert a date from external file, '|' separated txt file into teradata table, Please let me know the correct syntax

.IMPORT VARTEXT '|' FILE=/u/ps/ml/bin/1001_81136_201912051525.txt
.REPEAT *
USING
(
CUSTOMER_NBR            VARCHAR(100),
BIRTH_DATE              VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO TEST1.TEST
(
CUSTOMER_NBR,
BIRTH_DATE

VALUES
(
CUSTOMER_NBR,
trim (CAST(:BIRTH_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
);

Teradata column format : BIRTH_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' COMPRESS ,
sample data : 12345677|1988-12-12

Error Message :  *** Failure 2666 Invalid date supplied for WALMART_ONLN_CUSTOMER.CUST_BIRTH
_DATE.
Statement# 1, Info =0
*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Comment: Could be a typo, but try fixing the VALUES clause and removing the spurious TRIM `VALUES(:CUSTOMER_NBR, CAST(:BIRTH_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`. If you did need TRIM for some reason, it should be inside the CAST.

Comment: I tried removing the trim , still throwing same error

Comment: Did you add the comma in your values clause?  `VALUES (CUSTOMER_NBR, ...`.

Comment: Yes , i did. Let me correct the query

Comment: Then you must have some data that does not conform to the format. Since your format is yyyy-mm-dd, `TRYCAST(:BIRTH_DATE)` should convert valid data and return NULL for invalid data.

Comment: @Fred trycast worked